# Get Swing JFrame or AWT Frame from scala.swing application

Tags: swing, scala

I would like to embed a processing applet in a [scala.swing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-swing/#scala.swing.package) application. For this I need to set the `frame` member of [PApplet](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html). This requires a value of type java.awt.Frame. It seems to me scala.swing creates its counterparts for everything in Swing, `MainFrame` is derived from `scala.swing.Frame`, but I cannot find any references to `java.swing.JFrame` or `java.awt.Frame`.

How to I get an access to this from my class derived from scala.swing [MainFrame](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.swing.MainFrame)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each scala.swing wrapper the corresponding Swing component can be accessed in the `peer` member. See [The scala.swing package in 2.8 and beyond](http://ingomaier.blogspot.cz/2010/11/scalaswing-package-in-28-and-beyond.html).

> clients can get the underlying Java Swing component (the peer) of every wrapper